# Finding Distinct Eigenvalues (for some k)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\lceil -6,  k\rceil$
$\lfloor-9,  5\rfloor$

The matrix above, A, has two distinct eigenvalues if and only if $k < n$. The challenge is to find n. I take the det, and find $X^2 - 11x +30 -9k$. I'm unsure of how to pursue this after this point as I would think to have two distinct would mean $\lambda1 \not= \lambda2$, but am unsure of what one $\lambda$ would be. Perhaps that's not the right approach though.

Thanks very much,

Comment: you can think about $\Delta<0$

Comment: Ptiger17, your eigenvalues are over $\Bbb{R}$? If so, you need $\triangle>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that matrix had two eigenvalue if and only if $X^2-11X+30-9k$ had two roots so $\Delta=121-4(30-9k)=1+36k>0$ so $k<\frac{-1}{36}$

Comment: Thanks very much. I see that and found 11/2 as well. However, when I try $-1/36$ I still get the wrong answer. Any idea?

Comment: if you take $k=-1/36$ so you will have one eigenvalue because in this case $\Delta=0$ and the  eigenvalue is $11/2$ but for your case you need to take $k<-1/36$ and your eigenvalues are : $$ \lambda_{1,2}= \frac{11 \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2}=\frac{11 \pm \sqrt{1+36k}}{2}$$

Comment: ** Sorry, I mistakingly miswrote the result I got of the char. polynomial. Using your strategy I got the right answer. However, would you mind explaining how you rearranged to 121-4(30-9k)? I'm very rusty at my rearranging.

Comment: excuse me for my English first, but if i have understand your question you want me to explain how i have got $121-4(30-9k)$?

Comment: Yes, exactly :) How you went from $x^2 - 11x + 30 -9k$ to $121-4(30-9k)$

Comment: that's very simple, because our char. poly is of degree 2 so it had two roots if and only if the discriminant $\Delta$ is positive, I recall that for $aX^2+bX+c$ the discriminant is $\Delta=b^2-4ac$. that clear now ?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find $k$ such that $30 - 9k = (11/2)^2$. Can you see why that would make the matrix have only one distinct eigenvalue?

Comment: I get $k=-1/36$, but you're right I don't understand what this would only give one value?